# No horizontal page scroll when nowrap is set on DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a large number of DIVS in javascript, and that I don't want the page to be wrapped. When I set the nowrap on CSS, there is no horizontal scroll. Can anybody help me with that? My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/1/

JS:

```
var table_size=50;

for(var i=0;i<table_size;i++){
    $('#table').append("<div class='inline' id='"+i+"'>"+i+"</div>");
}
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    outline: black solid none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.inline {
    display:inline-block;
    width:18px;
    height:18px;
    border:1px solid;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id= "table" class="table"> </div>
```

Comment: Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/3/

Comment: Well, I have another Div coming on top of this table, so I need the main page to have the scroll, not my table!

Comment: Does your table have to be fixed?  If you remove that positioning, then the browser will scroll horizontally. http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/4/

Comment: Well, the left attribute should be fixed...Basically I don't want to change my current settings.

Comment: What about `margin-left` or `position:absolute?`  `position:fixed` means it won't move if you scroll vertically.

Comment: @TinaJasmin `position:fixed` WILL affect many "normal" flow. Your `<p>` in your fiddle is actually not rendered as a parent of your `<div>`, check your Chrome console; and since it's fixed, body scroll will not scroll the `<div>` -- that's what "fixed" mean (and that's why body does not generate a scroll for it). You'll have to rethink your layout.

Comment: Ummm, OK...My full code is a bit complex: http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `position: fixed` is the cause of this issue.  If your table doesn't need to be fixed, then you can remove that CSS rule and it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/4/

You can also use **`position:absolute`** and that will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/10/

If you want to use the browser scroll, and not put a scroll bar on the table then I think these are your only options with fixed positioned elements overflowing the body.

[**Here's your more complicated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/12/) with all `position:fixed` changed to `position:absolute`.

Comment: This works...but in my major project I am generally facing some positioning problems! Can you take a look at this: My full code is a bit complex: jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/7

Comment: But as you see, initially the window is on cell #1, not 0...how to fix it?

Comment: I did that, but unfortunately the window will then jump to 3 instead of 2 when apply is pressed!!

Comment: No changes. then the highlighting cells does not work...My code needs to be changed

Comment: What do you mean?  The highlighting cells doesn't work in your own fiddle.  Basically using `position: absolute` for all elements on a page is pretty bad.  There's no need.  For this you can use floats and margins etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the attempts so far. I'll fix it since I'm familiar with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/2/). Essentially, you just add:

```
.table
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: auto;
}
```

The `overflow-y: scroll` forces the `.table` div to add a scrollbar all the time. You can also set it to `auto` which will cause the scrollbar to disappear if the table does not completely fill the width of its parent (Or your screen).

**EDIT:**

Try [this new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/14/).

Simply change the `position: fixed` to `position: relative` and change `left: 20px` to `margin-left: 12px`.

Comment: Well, I have another Div later coming on top of this table, so I need the main page to have the scroll, not the table itself.

Comment: @TinaJasmin Please provide the fully code/markup then please. Otherwise we can't help. I would however, suggest possibly adding `overflow: auto` on either the parent of the `.table` div or the `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

The point of `white-space: nowrap` is to suppress line breaks so if you want the table to scroll, you'll need to add `overflow-x: scroll` in the `.table` rules.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/9/)

If you want the body to scroll, try these rules for `.table`

```
.table {
    height: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    outline: black solid none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UY4K3/15/)

Comment: I see; but it does not have a nice look though!

Comment: Edited with a new fiddle

Comment: Looks nice; but now the left property does not work!

Comment: Just add any positioning besides fixed